# which is best filter or directive in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, filter

I was trying to convert date string to formatted date. I found 3 options, Can someone help me which is best solution?

```
vm.dateString = "03-06-2015 12:11:00";

1. <div>{{convertToDate(vm.dateString)}}</div>
2. <div>{{vm.dateString | convertDate}}</div>

3. <div convertDate={{vm.dateString}}></div>

   someModule.directive('convertDate', function() {
     return {
       scope: {
         convertDate: '@'
       },
       controller : function($scope) {
         function convertToDate (dateString) {
           ....
           return date;
         }
         $scope.date = convertToDate($scope.converDate);
       },
       template: '{{date}}'
    };
  });
```

Answer (score 3):

I think the best way is to use a filter for this kind of task (Angular already have a built date filter. [Angular Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date))

**Because :**

For input => output, with some manipulations a filter is the best way.

**Why not directives  ?**

Directives are for dom manipulations, and they give you the tools for this.

**why not controllers ?**

Controllers have a control task they do not do the stuff, they delegate the work to others, this is one raison, the other, how could you use this logic globaly in your project if you need it ?

Comment: built date filter wont work in my case. Since it is not a date string they expect. Date to format either as Date object, milliseconds (string or number) or various ISO 8601 datetime string formats (e.g. yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.sssZ and its shorter versions like yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mmZ, yyyy-MM-dd or yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ).

Comment: @simon : I'm not telling you to use it (I know that you should have a custom filter ...), I just, explain angular it self use a filter for "this kind of task", directives are for dom manipulations, and they give you the tools for this, but, for input => output, with some manipulation a filter is the best way. clear ?

Comment: ok. That make sense. Then can you tell me what is the difference between my option 1 and 2?